# haskell - are tuples defined recursively?

Tags: haskell

1. Are n-tuples defined recursively in terms of 2-tuples, for example, are (a,b,c) and (a,(b,c)) the same?
2. If not, what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488228/disadvantage-of-unlifted-type-products

Answer (score 5):

**(a, (b, c))** is a 2-tuple whose second element happens to be another 2-tuple. If your suggestion had been adopted, it would not be possible to represent a tuple inside the final cell  of another tuple. Which would be a bizarrely asymmetric restriction and make tuples much less generally useful.

Comment: I am now confused. As lists are defined recursively in haskell, then it will not be possible to represent a list inside the final cell of another list?! I know that a:[b,c] and [a,b,c] are the same, but how about [a,[b,c]]?

Comment: Lists are defined recursively but not the way you think.  Firstly, you cannot have [a,[b,c]].  In Haskell lists, each element has to bee of the same type.  You can have a list of lists - [[a,b],[c,d,e],[]] - but not a list mixing non-lists and lists.  When you create **List a**, every element in the list has to be of type **a**.

Comment: Haskell lists are an Algebraic Data Type.  The definition is **data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)**. The recursion is in the *definition*, which defines **List** in terms of itself. **Nil** and **Cons a** are both constructors for **List a**.  **Nil** gives an empty list while **Cons a (List a)** prepends an element of type **a** onto an existing **List a**.  So [1,2,3] is actually **Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))**.

Comment: This is answer is simply a misunderstanding. With a slight variation to the posters example it is possible to represent every size of tuple using only 2-tuples. In [Ceylon](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Tuple.type.html) for example tuples are represented in such a way.

Answer (score 3):

1, No it's defined separately for each tuple. (So data (,) a b = (,) a b for the 2-tuple). 
You can see the full list(and limit that you can use) here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Tuple.html (also the comment about the number of n-tuples in the source is funny)

2, I would say performance but not sure about this.(Edit: see @itsbruce's answer for a better reason)

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what this resource does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: I've added a an example from the link but I don't think that copying stuff over here helps in this case.